# How many degrees can the Sniper Autoballista turn?

Tags: orcs-must-die

How many degrees can the Sniper Autoballista (upgraded [Autoballista](http://orcsmustdie.wikia.com/wiki/Autoballista)) turn? I was wondering if it could cover all sides at 360° or if I should put more to cover all sides.

[image: Screenshot of the Sniper Autoballista]

Comment: IIRC it can only shoot 90-degrees (directly in front of it), but it's been a while since I played.  Doesn't it show you the range when you build it?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It doesn't show the range that it can attack. But according to the [the answer by dpatchery](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77167/4797), there is a red zone indicating the range in which it can rotate. (I initially thought that the red zone was just to indicate which side the Autoballista will be set to face initially, and that it might be able to turn like an [Archer Guardian](http://orcsmustdie.wikia.com/wiki/Archer_Guardian).)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, the range of rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can attack in a semi circle (180 degrees) centered on the direction you face it. This is shown when you go to place the ballista and there is a red zone indicating the range in which it can rotate.

[image: Autoballista]

Comment: I see. I thought the red zone was just to indicate which side the Autoballista will be set to face initially. I also thought that it might work like the [Archer Guardian](http://orcsmustdie.wikia.com/wiki/Archer_Guardian) (which can be set to face any direction, but can seem to turn 360° to attack enemies).